'inject() must be called from an injection context' in Jest test code after upgrading Angular/Jest
Problem
Hi there, I recently upgraded my Angular app from v14 to v17, along with Jest from v27 to v29, and many other dependencies along the way.
I was able to get my app working correctly, and fix all linting errors, however, now that I got around to test code, almost all my Jest tests are failing.
The full error stack:
NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203

      at injectInjectorOnly (../ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1093:15)
      at ɵɵinject (../ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1106:42)
      at ɵɵdirectiveInject (../ui/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11047:16)
      at NodeInjectorFactory.HelpToggleDirective_Factory [as factory] (..\..\ng:\HelpToggleDirective\ɵfac.js:5:47)
      at getNodeInjectable (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5984:44)
      at instantiateAllDirectives (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11907:27)
      at createDirectivesInstances (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11306:5)
      at ɵɵelementStart (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:23014:9)
      at RegisterFormComponent_div_25_Template (../../ng:/RegisterFormComponent.js:143:32)
      at executeTemplate (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11268:9)
      at renderView (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12470:13)
      at createAndRenderEmbeddedLView (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12540:9)
      at TemplateRef2.createEmbeddedViewImpl (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13393:31)
      at ViewContainerRef2.createEmbeddedView (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:16191:37)
      at _NgIf._updateView (../../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:3408:61)
      at _NgIf.set ngIf [as ngIf] (../../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs:3382:14)
      at applyValueToInputField (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4035:29)
      at writeToDirectiveInput (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11096:13)
      at setInputsForProperty (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12391:9)
      at elementPropertyInternal (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11692:9)
      at ɵɵproperty (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:21258:9)
      at RegisterFormComponent_Template (../../ng:/RegisterFormComponent.js:413:9)
      at executeTemplate (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11268:9)
      at refreshView (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12791:13)
      at detectChangesInView$1 (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13015:9)
      at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12978:5)
      at detectChangesInComponent (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12967:5)
      at detectChangesInChildComponents (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13028:9)
      at refreshView (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12841:13)
      at detectChangesInView$1 (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13015:9)
      at detectChangesInViewWhileDirty (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12732:5)
      at detectChangesInternal (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12714:9)
      at ViewRef$1.detectChanges (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:13310:9)
      at ../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:353:36
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:411:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:300:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:410:56)
      at Object.onInvoke (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14882:33)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:410:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:166:47)
      at NgZone.run (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14733:28)
      at PseudoApplicationComponentFixture.detectChanges (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:352:22)
      at src/tests/register/register-form.component.spec.ts:42:11
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:411:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:300:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:410:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:166:47)
      at Object.wrappedFunc (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:789:34)

It seems that my HelpDirective is causing issues after the update, possible due to changes in injection implementation.
Current Setup
Angular Version: 17.3.4
Jest Version: 29.7.0
Node Version: 20.11.1
Typescript Version: 5.4.3
My test-setup.ts (runs before every test suite):
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import '@angular/localize/init';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

getTestBed().resetTestEnvironment();
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
  { teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false } }
);

And example beforeEach from one of my failing tests:
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CoreTestingModule,
                NgbTooltipModule
            ],
            providers: [
                RegistrationService,
                RegistrationResource,
                AuthService,
                AuthResource
            ],
            declarations: [
                RegisterFormComponent
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        router = TestBed.inject(Router);
        resource = TestBed.inject(RegistrationResource);
        authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegisterFormComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges(); // ERROR HAPPENS HERE: Always happens at the first fixture.detectChanges()

        jest.spyOn(router, 'navigate').mockReturnValue(null);
    });

My Help Directive:
/**
 * Parent used to control the toggling of the alert
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[icmHelp]',
    exportAs: 'icmHelp'
})
export class HelpDirective {
    /**
     * If the alert is open or closed
     */
    @Input()
    public toggle: boolean = false;

    /**
     * If the alert should be forced open
     */
    @Input()
    public set forceShow(show: boolean) {
        if (show) {
            this.toggle = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * If the alert should be shown on print
     */
    @Input() showOnPrint: boolean = false;

    /**
     * Help alert that this belongs to for testing purposes
     */
    _helpAlert: HelpAlertComponent;
}

/**
 * Ngb alert to show
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'icm-help-alert',
    templateUrl: `help.component.html`,
})
export class HelpAlertComponent {
    @Input() alertClass: string;
    @Input() wrapperClass: string;
    @Input() formHelp: boolean = false;
    @Input() innerHTML: string = '';
    show: boolean = false;

    /**
     * Input to show more component, integer value in pixels
     * Will truncate alert container below the max height
     */
    @Input() MaxHeight: number;

    /**
     * Input to show more component
     * Will truncate alert container after MaxLines number of lines of text
     *
     * Note - Should only use for text-only alerts
     */
    @Input() MaxLines: number;

    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => HelpDirective)) public parent: HelpDirective, public el: ElementRef) {
        this.parent._helpAlert = this;
    }
}

/**
 * used to toggle the alert
 */
@Directive({
    selector: 'a[icmHelpToggle]',
    host: {
        '(click)': 'parent.toggle = !parent.toggle'
    }
})

export class HelpToggleDirective {
    constructor(public parent: HelpDirective) {}
}

What I have Tried
Using information from this GitHub Issue, I checked to see if any of my npm packages (especially test related ones) had dependencies to @angular/core. Everything seemed to be up to date there, and I was unable to get this to work.
I tried following along with this article and tried adding Router to providers as follows: { provide: Router, useValue: router } where router uses jest.spyOn().
I tried wrapping any erroring sections in runInInjectionContext(TestBed, () => { // Erroring Code Here });
I tried removing the @Inject property from the HelpAlertComponent so that the constructor became:
    // Other declarations removed for brevity
    public parent: HelpDirective = inject(forwardRef(() => HelpDirective));

    constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
        this.parent._helpAlert = this;
    }

